# The legend is not displayed correctly

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

In general, I'm trying to draw a simple graph through OpenXML, but I don’t understand why the clumsy legend is obtained:

[image]

I expect to see “Итого” on the right, and get a set of header values.

I can’t understand what is missing in the Chart.xml structure to get the idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<c:chartSpace xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart">
    <c:lang val="en-US"/>
    <c:chart>
        <c:title>
            <c:tx>
                <c:rich>
                    <a:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="0" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
                    <a:lstStyle xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
                    <a:p xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                        <a:r>
                            <a:rPr lang="ru-RU" sz="1300" b="0" i="1" baseline="0">
                                <a:latin typeface="Calibri"/>
                            </a:rPr>
                            <a:t>Тест 2</a:t>
                        </a:r>
                    </a:p>
                </c:rich>
            </c:tx>
            <c:layout/>
            <c:overlay val="0"/>
        </c:title>
        <c:plotArea>
            <c:layout/>
            <c:lineChart>
                <c:ser>
                    <c:idx val="0"/>
                    <c:order val="0"/>
                    <c:tx>
                        <c:strRef>
                            <c:f>'Лист1'!$A$2</c:f>
                        </c:strRef>
                    </c:tx>
                    <c:marker>
                        <c:symbol val="circle"/>
                        <c:size val="5"/>
                    </c:marker>
                    <c:cat>
                        <c:strRef>
                            <c:f>'Лист1'!$B$1:$E$1</c:f>
                        </c:strRef>
                    </c:cat>
                    <c:val>
                        <c:numRef>
                            <c:f>'Лист1'!$B$2:$E$2</c:f>
                        </c:numRef>
                    </c:val>
                </c:ser>
                <c:axId val="213998592"/>
                <c:axId val="213999768"/>
            </c:lineChart>
            <c:catAx>
                <c:axId val="213998592"/>
                <c:scaling>
                    <c:orientation val="minMax"/>
                </c:scaling>
                <c:axPos val="b"/>
                <c:delete val="0"/>
                <c:majorTickMark val="out"/>
                <c:minorTickMark val="none"/>
                <c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>
                <c:crossAx val="213999768"/>
                <c:crosses val="autoZero"/>
                <c:auto val="1"/>
                <c:lblAlgn val="ctr"/>
                <c:lblOffset val="100"/>
            </c:catAx>
            <c:valAx>
                <c:axId val="213999768"/>
                <c:scaling>
                    <c:orientation val="minMax"/>
                </c:scaling>
                <c:axPos val="l"/>
                <c:delete val="0"/>
                <c:majorTickMark val="out"/>
                <c:minorTickMark val="none"/>
                <c:majorGridlines/>
                <c:numFmt formatCode="General" sourceLinked="1"/>
                <c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>
                <c:crossAx val="213998592"/>
                <c:crosses val="autoZero"/>
                <c:crossBetween val="between"/>
            </c:valAx>
        </c:plotArea>
        <c:legend>
            <c:legendPos val="r"/>
            <c:overlay val="0"/>
            <c:layout/>
        </c:legend>
        <c:plotVisOnly val="1"/>
    </c:chart>
</c:chartSpace>
```

I tried the office to do the same thing, and then look at the result, it turns out to be 300+ lines and if you drop all sorts of styles and look at ranges, then everything + looks like ... What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<c:chartSpace xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:c16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/06/chart">
    <c:date1904 val="0"/>
    <c:lang val="ru-RU"/>
    <c:roundedCorners val="0"/>
    <mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
        <mc:Choice Requires="c14" xmlns:c14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2007/8/2/chart">
            <c14:style val="102"/>
        </mc:Choice>
        <mc:Fallback>
            <c:style val="2"/>
        </mc:Fallback>
    </mc:AlternateContent>
    <c:chart>
        <c:title>
            <c:layout/>
            <c:overlay val="0"/>
            <c:spPr>
                <a:noFill/>
                <a:ln>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </a:ln>
                <a:effectLst/>
            </c:spPr>
            <c:txPr>
                <a:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/>
                <a:lstStyle/>
                <a:p>
                    <a:pPr>
                        <a:defRPr sz="1400" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" spc="0" baseline="0">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                                    <a:lumMod val="65000"/>
                                    <a:lumOff val="35000"/>
                                </a:schemeClr>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
                            <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
                            <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
                        </a:defRPr>
                    </a:pPr>
                    <a:endParaRPr lang="ru-RU"/>
                </a:p>
            </c:txPr>
        </c:title>
        <c:autoTitleDeleted val="0"/>
        <c:plotArea>
            <c:layout/>
            <c:lineChart>
                <c:grouping val="standard"/>
                <c:varyColors val="0"/>
                <c:ser>
                    <c:idx val="0"/>
                    <c:order val="0"/>
                    <c:tx>
                        <c:strRef>
                            <c:f>Лист1!$A$2</c:f>
                            <c:strCache>
                                <c:ptCount val="1"/>
                                <c:pt idx="0">
                                    <c:v>Итого</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                            </c:strCache>
                        </c:strRef>
                    </c:tx>
                    <c:spPr>
                        <a:ln w="28575" cap="rnd">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:round/>
                        </a:ln>
                        <a:effectLst/>
                    </c:spPr>
                    <c:marker>
                        <c:symbol val="circle"/>
                        <c:size val="5"/>
                        <c:spPr>
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:ln w="9525">
                                <a:solidFill>
                                    <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                                </a:solidFill>
                            </a:ln>
                            <a:effectLst/>
                        </c:spPr>
                    </c:marker>
                    <c:cat>
                        <c:strRef>
                            <c:f>Лист1!$B$1:$E$1</c:f>
                            <c:strCache>
                                <c:ptCount val="4"/>
                                <c:pt idx="0">
                                    <c:v>G1</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                                <c:pt idx="1">
                                    <c:v>G2</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                                <c:pt idx="2">
                                    <c:v>G3</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                                <c:pt idx="3">
                                    <c:v>G4</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                            </c:strCache>
                        </c:strRef>
                    </c:cat>
                    <c:val>
                        <c:numRef>
                            <c:f>Лист1!$B$2:$E$2</c:f>
                            <c:numCache>
                                <c:formatCode>General</c:formatCode>
                                <c:ptCount val="4"/>
                                <c:pt idx="0">
                                    <c:v>1</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                                <c:pt idx="1">
                                    <c:v>2</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                                <c:pt idx="2">
                                    <c:v>3</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                                <c:pt idx="3">
                                    <c:v>4</c:v>
                                </c:pt>
                            </c:numCache>
                        </c:numRef>
                    </c:val>
                    <c:smooth val="0"/>
                    <c:extLst>
                        <c:ext uri="{C3380CC4-5D6E-409C-BE32-E72D297353CC}" xmlns:c16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chart">
                            <c16:uniqueId val="{00000002-8D1A-4BF3-926D-4E6D0E7F2B04}"/>
                        </c:ext>
                    </c:extLst>
                </c:ser>
                <c:dLbls>
                    <c:showLegendKey val="0"/>
                    <c:showVal val="0"/>
                    <c:showCatName val="0"/>
                    <c:showSerName val="0"/>
                    <c:showPercent val="0"/>
                    <c:showBubbleSize val="0"/>
                </c:dLbls>
                <c:marker val="1"/>
                <c:smooth val="0"/>
                <c:axId val="89036176"/>
                <c:axId val="89032848"/>
            </c:lineChart>
            <c:catAx>
                <c:axId val="89036176"/>
                <c:scaling>
                    <c:orientation val="minMax"/>
                </c:scaling>
                <c:delete val="0"/>
                <c:axPos val="b"/>
                <c:numFmt formatCode="General" sourceLinked="1"/>
                <c:majorTickMark val="none"/>
                <c:minorTickMark val="none"/>
                <c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>
                <c:spPr>
                    <a:noFill/>
                    <a:ln w="9525" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr">
                        <a:solidFill>
                            <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                                <a:lumMod val="15000"/>
                                <a:lumOff val="85000"/>
                            </a:schemeClr>
                        </a:solidFill>
                        <a:round/>
                    </a:ln>
                    <a:effectLst/>
                </c:spPr>
                <c:txPr>
                    <a:bodyPr rot="-60000000" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:pPr>
                            <a:defRPr sz="900" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" baseline="0">
                                <a:solidFill>
                                    <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                                        <a:lumMod val="65000"/>
                                        <a:lumOff val="35000"/>
                                    </a:schemeClr>
                                </a:solidFill>
                                <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
                                <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
                                <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
                            </a:defRPr>
                        </a:pPr>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="ru-RU"/>
                    </a:p>
                </c:txPr>
                <c:crossAx val="89032848"/>
                <c:crosses val="autoZero"/>
                <c:auto val="1"/>
                <c:lblAlgn val="ctr"/>
                <c:lblOffset val="100"/>
                <c:noMultiLvlLbl val="0"/>
            </c:catAx>
            <c:valAx>
                <c:axId val="89032848"/>
                <c:scaling>
                    <c:orientation val="minMax"/>
                </c:scaling>
                <c:delete val="0"/>
                <c:axPos val="l"/>
                <c:majorGridlines>
                    <c:spPr>
                        <a:ln w="9525" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                                    <a:lumMod val="15000"/>
                                    <a:lumOff val="85000"/>
                                </a:schemeClr>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:round/>
                        </a:ln>
                        <a:effectLst/>
                    </c:spPr>
                </c:majorGridlines>
                <c:numFmt formatCode="General" sourceLinked="1"/>
                <c:majorTickMark val="none"/>
                <c:minorTickMark val="none"/>
                <c:tickLblPos val="nextTo"/>
                <c:spPr>
                    <a:noFill/>
                    <a:ln>
                        <a:noFill/>
                    </a:ln>
                    <a:effectLst/>
                </c:spPr>
                <c:txPr>
                    <a:bodyPr rot="-60000000" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/>
                    <a:lstStyle/>
                    <a:p>
                        <a:pPr>
                            <a:defRPr sz="900" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" baseline="0">
                                <a:solidFill>
                                    <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                                        <a:lumMod val="65000"/>
                                        <a:lumOff val="35000"/>
                                    </a:schemeClr>
                                </a:solidFill>
                                <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
                                <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
                                <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
                            </a:defRPr>
                        </a:pPr>
                        <a:endParaRPr lang="ru-RU"/>
                    </a:p>
                </c:txPr>
                <c:crossAx val="89036176"/>
                <c:crosses val="autoZero"/>
                <c:crossBetween val="between"/>
            </c:valAx>
            <c:spPr>
                <a:noFill/>
                <a:ln>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </a:ln>
                <a:effectLst/>
            </c:spPr>
        </c:plotArea>
        <c:legend>
            <c:legendPos val="r"/>
            <c:layout/>
            <c:overlay val="0"/>
            <c:spPr>
                <a:noFill/>
                <a:ln>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </a:ln>
                <a:effectLst/>
            </c:spPr>
            <c:txPr>
                <a:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="1" vertOverflow="ellipsis" vert="horz" wrap="square" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="1"/>
                <a:lstStyle/>
                <a:p>
                    <a:pPr>
                        <a:defRPr sz="900" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike" kern="1200" baseline="0">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                                    <a:lumMod val="65000"/>
                                    <a:lumOff val="35000"/>
                                </a:schemeClr>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:latin typeface="+mn-lt"/>
                            <a:ea typeface="+mn-ea"/>
                            <a:cs typeface="+mn-cs"/>
                        </a:defRPr>
                    </a:pPr>
                    <a:endParaRPr lang="ru-RU"/>
                </a:p>
            </c:txPr>
        </c:legend>
        <c:plotVisOnly val="1"/>
        <c:dispBlanksAs val="zero"/>
        <c:showDLblsOverMax val="0"/>
    </c:chart>
    <c:spPr>
        <a:solidFill>
            <a:schemeClr val="bg1"/>
        </a:solidFill>
        <a:ln w="9525" cap="flat" cmpd="sng" algn="ctr">
            <a:solidFill>
                <a:schemeClr val="tx1">
                    <a:lumMod val="15000"/>
                    <a:lumOff val="85000"/>
                </a:schemeClr>
            </a:solidFill>
            <a:round/>
        </a:ln>
        <a:effectLst/>
    </c:spPr>
    <c:txPr>
        <a:bodyPr/>
        <a:lstStyle/>
        <a:p>
            <a:pPr>
                <a:defRPr/>
            </a:pPr>
            <a:endParaRPr lang="ru-RU"/>
        </a:p>
    </c:txPr>
    <c:printSettings>
        <c:headerFooter/>
        <c:pageMargins b="0.75" l="0.7" r="0.7" t="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
        <c:pageSetup/>
    </c:printSettings>
</c:chartSpace>
```